# rdlc-Report reproduce Textboxes

Tags: string, textbox, rdlc

i placed on my report 3 textboxes, which contains string-values.
That look like this:

```
<TextRuns>
   <TextRun>
      <Value>Title1:</Value>
         <Style>
           <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
           <Color>Blue</Color>
         </Style>
    </TextRun>
 </TextRuns>
```

Under this texboxes i have variable values.
Sadly on the next site of my report, this three boxes do not appear. 
These appear only on first page.

How can i reproduce textboxes with strings programmaticaly, as i have number of pages?

thx.

Comment: Without knowing anything about other data in your report...
Try to place them into Tablix header and set it to repeat on each page?

Comment: thx. for your answer.
i am new in reporting-things. 
I load my data into the list.

For Each Column i have textbox-titel, something like this:

firstname          secondname           birthday

And if i need second site, i want to generate this 3 text-boxes on the second page too.

How i can do that?